# Is there a native way to cancel async task in swiftui, after view disappears?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I work in ios 13 and with Swift Concurrency. I can't use .task(). What I do now is collect all tasks, and then cancel them when view disappears. Shounldn't there be a native way to do this?

Comment: Can you show an example of whet you do ?

Comment: E.g. loading data view appears and when view disappears, i don't want the loaded data to be assigned anywhere. This can be done by calling .cancel() in .onDisappear, but wondering if there is a better way

Comment: “.task” is the native way in the if you can’t support that onAppear/onDisappear or init/deinit